# Set date of calendar

Tags: java, calendar

Ok, so what I'm trying to do is to set the set the date of a calendar instance, and then return the week_of_year. I am doing so by using the Calendar.set() functio

```
public String weekInYearForm = "ww";
SimpleDateFormat formWIM = new SimpleDateFormat(weekInYearForm, Locale.US);

Calendar lc = Calendar.getInstance();
    lc.set(Calendar.YEAR, lYear);
    lc.set(Calendar.MONTH, lMonth);
    lc.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, lDay);


    wiy = formWIM.format(lc.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

To get the lYear, lMonth, and lDay values, I am passing a string in the format `04/26/2013` to through the following steps:

```
String[] arrDate = dateIn.split("/");
int lMonth = Integer.parseInt(arrDate[0]) - 1;
Log.d("SaveHandler", "Month is: " + lMonth);
int lDay = Integer.parseInt(arrDate[1]);
Log.d("SaveHandler", "Day is: " + lDay);
int lYear = Integer.parseInt(arrDate[2]);
Log.d("SaveHandler", "Year is: " + lYear);
```

The problem I am facing is that when I look at what is outputed to wiy, it is always 1. Upon some further debugging, I realized that the time is being left at epoch time, and not setting to the values I need.

I also tried using `lc.set(lYear, lMonth, lDay)`, also to no avail. If anyone has any ideas, I would greatly appreciate them.

*EDIT: I did some debugging earlier and it is returning 1970 for the year and 0 for the month.

Comment: The `Calendar.MONTH` field on `Calendar` is 0 based, not 1 (as we're used to). Maybe there's your problem.

Comment: No, I had thought about that and am subtracting 1 from it before I try to set it.

Comment: Do you must use Java classes or use a third party library like Joda Time which already solves all these problems?

Comment: Using the java classes. I'm writing an Android app and don't want to import extra libraries.

Comment: Calendar should be preset with current Date - also a function "setTime(Date)" should be present. What is "formWIM"? Try to use a debugger.

Comment: What is `formWIM`? Your problem may be one if formatting. What is output from `lc.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR)`?

Comment: Please, show `lYear`, `lMonth` and `lDay` values

Comment: If you call lc.getTime(), what do you get?

Comment: I've updated to show how I'm getting the lValues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

```
formWIM.format(lc.getTime());
```

instead of

```
formWIM.format(lc.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR));
```

**EDIT**
You can parse your date (instead of `dateIn.split(` etc.)

```
  SimpleDateFormat monthDayYear = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy", Locale.US); //04/26/2013
  Date date = monthDayYear.parse("04/26/2013");
```

and then format it

```
 SimpleDateFormat formWIM = new SimpleDateFormat("ww", Locale.US);  
 formWIM.format(date);
```

Comment: Yes, this has fixed it. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

**This code is correct**, the problem is in `formWIM.format(...)` or the battery of your motherboard clock is drained.